# Use jquery to highlight parent when child menu item is active and keep submenu open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm new to jQuery and working on a vertical accordion type navigation that will highlight  the active page and parent level element if there is one. I pretty much have it working the way I want it to with a few exceptions. However, I'm sure there must be a way to condense all of the functions into one, I'm just not sure how.

Most of my pages are within folders that have a main default page and then other pages. So if I had `about` on my menu and it had a submenu, the submenu would be open and `about` would be highlighted with an active class. Then if you click on a page within the about folder, `about` would remain highlighted and the submenu item would also be highlighted. And you would be able to have parent level links and still toggle the submenu.

**[Here is an example page](http://www.goodwin.edu/test/addbutton/)**

I also [have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnccdbs7/), but you can't see all of the functionality

Here are the problems I would like to correct:

1. When you land on the main page, nothing is highlighted until you click on an item.
2. When hovering on a parent level link with an arrow, the arrow remains
   dark instead of white. Haven't been able to figure out the css class
   for this.
3. When clicking on a parent level link that has a submenu, the submenu
   stays open. But if you toggle the menu closed with the arrow, the
   arrow remains in the down position instead of to the right.

This function accomplishes adding an independent toggling element

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(function() {  
        // Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside
        $('#vmenuList li').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i class="icon"></i></span>');
        // Dynamic binding to on 'click'
        $('#vmenuList').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){
            // Toggle the nested nav
            $(this).siblings('.submenu').slideToggle('slow');
            // Toggle the arrow using CSS3 transforms
            $(this).children('.icon').toggleClass('nav-open');
        });
    });
});
```

This matches the url and applies an active class

```
$(function() {
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href;

    // passes on every "a" tag
    $("#vmenuList a").each(function() {
        // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if (url == (this.href)) {
            $(this).closest("a").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

This adds a parent class to the closest parent (if there is one) so that it can also be highlighted. It also add an open class to keep the submenu open if the user is on a submenu link.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function() {  
        $(".active").closest("#vmenuList > li").addClass("parent open");
    });
});
```

I'm also using jquery cookie to remember the menu item although I'm not sure if it's necessary

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
    if (checkCookie != "") {
        $('#vmenuList > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').next().show();
    }
    $('#vmenuList > li > a').click(function(){
        var navIndex = $('#vmenuList > li > a').index(this);
        $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
        $('#vmenuList li ul').slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        }
        $('#vmenuList li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your questions one by one:

> 1. When you land on the main page, nothing is highlighted until you click on an item.

This is most probably due to the fact that your links are not identical to the output of your `url` variable. Test it by doing `console.log(url)` and you'll see if you got it right.

I setup the URL of the first menu item with the correct link, so you can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/rnccdbs7/2/

> 2. When hovering on a parent level link with an arrow, the arrow remains dark instead of white. Haven't been able to figure out the css class for this.

This is because you're only targeting the icon with `hover`, instead of the full menu item, so remove this...

```css
.nav-click:hover .icon { background: url('http://www.goodwin.edu/test/addbutton/rightwhite.png') no-repeat center center; }
```

...and add this instead...

```css
#verticalmenu #vmenuList > li:hover .icon { background: url('http://www.goodwin.edu/test/addbutton/rightwhite.png') no-repeat center center; }
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rnccdbs7/1/

> 3. When clicking on a parent level link that has a submenu, the submenu stays open. But if you toggle the menu closed with the arrow, the arrow remains in the down position instead of to the right.

These are actually 2 issues: **A.** clicking the parent menu doesn't collapse it, and **B.** the down/right icon state doesn't change.

And here are the answers to those:

**A. Menu not collapsing:** looks like the `href` attribute of the main element has a valid url, so it redirects to that page instead of just taking care of the menu collapsing / expanding. This works ok on your fiddle example as that has a hash (`#`) in its `href` tag.

**B. Arrow not changing:** the problem stems from the fact that the `open` / `nav-open` classes remain on `li.parent` and `i.icon` respectively. You'll have to have a deeper look into your plugin (or script) as to how the collapsing / expanding state changing mechanisms work and ensure the above classes are removed when you're collapsing the menus.